# ¿Cómo crear varias páginas pdf en TCPDF de manera dinámica?

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

El detalle es que estoy creando pdf, a traves de **ids**, lo cual que si ingreso un solo **id**, crea el documento todo bien con su información que necesita pero, cuando paso dos ids ahí genera el problema, porque cuando los mando me aparece de la siguiente manera:

```
Datos del cliente
Nombre : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
apellido: xxxxxxxxxxxx

Datos del cliente
Nombre : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
apellido: xxxxxxxxxxxx

Domicilio 
calle:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
colonia: xxxxxxxxx

Domicilio 
calle:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
colonia: xxxxxxxxx
```

Lo cual yo requiero que me salga de la siguiente manera:

```
Nombre : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
apellido: xxxxxxxxxxxx


Domicilio 
calle:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
colonia: xxxxxxxxx

Datos del cliente
Nombre : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
apellido: xxxxxxxxxxxx


Domicilio 
calle:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
colonia: xxxxxxxxx
```

No sé si me di a entender, pero serían de gran ayuda si alguien ha manejado la librería de **tcpdf**. Este es mi código:

```
public function impresion_masiva($ids){

        $ventas  = $this->ventasModel->getVentasExportar($ids);
        $partidas  = $this->ventasModel->getPartidasExportar($ids);
        $abonos = $this->ventasModel->getAbonosExportar($ids);
        $empresa = $this->configuracionesModel->getEmpresa();
        $rutas = $this->ventasModel->getRuta();

        foreach ($ventas as $row):
            $status = '';
            //condicion para tipo Estatus (1: Pedido / 2: Venta Abierta / 3: Venta Cerrada)
            if($row->ve_etapa ==1){
                $status = 'PEDIDO';
            }else if(($row->ve_etapa ==2 || $row->ve_etapa ==3)&&($row->ve_porcentaje_maquila==0 || $row->ve_porcentaje_abonos==0 || $row->ve_porcentaje_entrega==0)){
                $status = 'VENTA ABIERTA';
            }else if($row->ve_etapa==3 && $row->ve_porcentaje_maquila==1 && $row->ve_porcentaje_abonos==1 && $row->ve_porcentaje_entrega==1){
                $status = 'VENTA CERRADA';
            }

            //Condicion para el tipo de fecha
            if($row->ve_etapa==1){
                $tipoFecha = 'FECHA DE PEDIDO';
                $fecha = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row->ve_fecha_pedido));
            }else if($row->ve_etapa==2){
                $tipoFecha = 'FECHA DE PEDIDO';
                $fecha = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row->ve_fecha_pedido));
            }else if($row->ve_etapa==3){
                $tipoFecha = 'FECHA DE VENTA';
                $fecha = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row->ve_fecha_venta));
            }

        define ('PDF_HEADER_LOGO', $empresa->em_logo);

        define ('PDF_HEADER_TITLE', $empresa->em_razon_social);

        define ('PDF_HEADER_STRING', "R.F.C. ".strtoupper($empresa->em_rfc)."\nC.U.R.P".strtoupper($empresa->em_curp)."\nTel./Fax ".$empresa->em_telefono."\n".$empresa->em_correo_ventas."\n".wordwrap($empresa->em_calle.' Nº '.$empresa->em_numero_exterior.' Col. '.$empresa->em_colonia.' '.$empresa->ci_nombre.', '.$empresa->es_nombre,48,"\n"));

        $leyenda = "NOTA: ESTE DOCUMENTO\nNO REPRESENTA UN COMPROBANTE FISCAL";
        $leyenda2 = "-SE FACTURA AL PAGO-";
        $firma = "FIRMA DE CONFORMIDAD____________________";

        define('PDF_HEADER_DATA', $status."\n# ".$row->ve_id_venta."\n\n".$tipoFecha."\n".$fecha);

        define('PDF_FOOTER_DATA', $leyenda);
        define('PDF_FOOTER_TITLE', $leyenda2);
        define('PDF_FOOTER_FIRMA', $firma);
        $this->load->library('Pdf');
        $pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'A5', true, 'UTF-8', false);
        $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
        $pdf->SetAuthor('Ma.Concepción Hernández García');
        $pdf->SetTitle('Reporte PDF de Venta a '.date("Y-m-d h:m:s"));
        $pdf->SetSubject('Usuarios');
        $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');
 tcpdf_config_alt.php de libraries/config
        $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING, PDF_HEADER_DATA);
        $pdf->setFooterData(PDF_FOOTER_DATA, PDF_FOOTER_TITLE, PDF_FOOTER_FIRMA);
        $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
        $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
        $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
        $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
        $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
        $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
        $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
        $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
        $pdf->SetFont('freemono', '', 14, '', true);
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->setTextShadow(array('disable' => true, 'depth_w' => 0.2, 'depth_h' => 0.2, 'color' => array(196, 196, 196), 'opacity' => 1, 'blend_mode' => 'Normal'));

        //$pdf->writeHTMLCell($w = 0, $h = 0, $x = '', $y = '', $html, $border = 0, $ln = 1, $fill = 0, $reseth = true, $align = '', $autopadding = true);

        $nombre_archivo = utf8_decode("Pedidos_".date("Ymdhms").".pdf");
        $pdf->Output($nombre_archivo, 'I');
        endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que en el código no logro encontrar dónde es que escribes los datos que comentas, de hecho, en tu código no escribes nada en el PDF. Por lo tanto daré una respuesta genérica.

El método AddPage() crea una nueva página, por lo que simplemente tendrías que ponerlo como primera línea dentro del loop.

```
$pdf->SetFont("","",12);
foreach($dataArray as $data) {
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->MultiCell(0, 6, $data);
}
```

Este código creará un documento con tantas páginas como elementos tenga $dataArray y en cada una vendrá el contenido de texto con formato previo que tengan los elementos de $dataArray.

Answer (score 0):

Yo recomendaria que utilices DomPDF, siento que te da varias opciones que te permitiran a partir de un simple html convertirlo a pdf